# Trouble with stricter lifetime requirements when implementing FromIterator for LazyList

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I was playing with the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40690020/5600363%5D) but the FromIterator impl does not compile any more:

```
error[E0276]: impl has stricter requirements than trait    --> src/lib.rs:184:9
    | 184 |         fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = T> + 'a>(itrbl: I) -> LazyList<'a, T> {
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ impl has extra requirement `I: 'a`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0276`.
```

The slightly updated [code is on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2d05f0f4495ebef101857a7e4e3b3907).

```rust
// only necessary because Box<FnOnce() -> R> doesn't work...
mod thunk {
    pub trait Invoke<R = ()> {
        fn invoke(self: Box<Self>) -> R;
    }

    impl<R, F: FnOnce() -> R> Invoke<R> for F {
        #[inline(always)]
        fn invoke(self: Box<F>) -> R { (*self)() }
    }
}

// Lazy is lazily evaluated contained value using the above Invoke trait
// instead of the desire Box<FnOnce() -> T> or a stable FnBox (currently not)...
pub mod lazy {
    use crate::thunk::Invoke;
    use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
    use std::mem::replace;
    use std::ops::Deref;

    // Lazy is lazily evaluated contained value using the above Invoke trait
    // instead of the desire Box<FnOnce() -> T> or a stable FnBox (currently not)...
    pub struct Lazy<'a, T: 'a>(UnsafeCell<LazyState<'a, T>>);

    enum LazyState<'a, T: 'a> {
        Unevaluated(Box<dyn Invoke<T> + 'a>),
        EvaluationInProgress,
        Evaluated(T),
    }

    use self::LazyState::*;

    impl<'a, T: 'a> Lazy<'a, T> {
        #[inline]
        pub fn new<F: 'a + FnOnce() -> T>(func: F) -> Lazy<'a, T> {
            Lazy(UnsafeCell::new(Unevaluated(Box::new(func))))
        }
        #[inline]
        pub fn evaluated(val: T) -> Lazy<'a, T> {
            Lazy(UnsafeCell::new(Evaluated(val)))
        }
        #[inline(always)]
        fn force(&self) {
            unsafe {
                match *self.0.get() {
                    Evaluated(_) => {}, // nothing required; already Evaluated
                    EvaluationInProgress => panic!("Lazy::force called recursively!!!"),
                    _ => {
                        let ue = replace(&mut *self.0.get(), EvaluationInProgress);
                        if let Unevaluated(thnk) = ue {
                            *self.0.get() = Evaluated(thnk.invoke());
                        } // no other possiblity!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #[inline]
        pub fn unwrap<'b>(self) -> T where T: 'b { // consumes the object to produce the value
            self.force(); // evaluatate if not evealutated
            match { self.0.into_inner() } {
                Evaluated(v) => v,
                _ => unreachable!() // previous code guarantees never not Evaluated
            }
        }
    }

    impl<'a, T: 'a> Deref for Lazy<'a, T> {
        type Target = T;
        #[inline]
        fn deref(&self) -> &T {
            self.force(); // evaluatate if not evalutated
            match *unsafe { &*self.0.get() } {
                Evaluated(ref v) => v,
                _ => unreachable!(),
            }
        }
    }
}

// LazyList is an immutable lazily-evaluated persistent (memoized) singly-linked list
// similar to lists in Haskell, although here only tails are lazy...
//   depends on the contained type being Clone so that the LazyList can be
//   extracted from the reference-counted Rc heap objects in which embedded.
pub mod lazylist {
    use crate::lazy::Lazy;
    use std::rc::Rc;
    use std::iter::FromIterator;
    use std::mem::{replace, swap};

    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub enum LazyList<'a, T: 'a + Clone> {
        Empty,
        Cons(T, RcLazyListNode<'a, T>),
    }

    pub use self::LazyList::Empty;
    use self::LazyList::Cons;

    type RcLazyListNode<'a, T> = Rc<Lazy<'a, LazyList<'a, T>>>;

//  impl<'a, T:'a> !Sync for LazyList<'a, T> {}

    impl<'a, T: 'a + Clone> LazyList<'a, T> {
        #[inline]
        pub fn singleton(v: T) -> LazyList<'a, T> {
            Cons(v, Rc::new(Lazy::evaluated(Empty)))
        }
        #[inline]
        pub fn cons<F>(v: T, cntf: F) -> LazyList<'a, T>
            where F: 'a + FnOnce() -> LazyList<'a, T>
        {
            Cons(v, Rc::new(Lazy::new(cntf)))
        }
        #[inline]
        pub fn head(&self) -> &T {
            if let Cons(ref hd, _) = *self {
                return hd;
            }
            panic!("LazyList::head called on an Empty LazyList!!!")
        }
        #[inline]
        pub fn tail<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b Lazy<'a, LazyList<'a, T>> {
            if let Cons(_, ref rlln) = *self {
                return &*rlln;
            }
            panic!("LazyList::tail called on an Empty LazyList!!!")
        }
        #[inline]
        pub fn unwrap(self) -> (T, RcLazyListNode<'a, T>) {
            // consumes the object
            if let Cons(hd, rlln) = self {
                return (hd, rlln);
            }
            panic!("LazyList::unwrap called on an Empty LazyList!!!")
        }
        #[inline]
        fn iter(&self) -> Iter<'a, T> {
            Iter(self)
        }
    }

    impl<'a, T: 'a + Clone> Iterator for LazyList<'a, T> {
        type Item = T;

        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
            match replace(self, Empty) {
                Cons(hd, rlln) => {
                    let mut newll = (*rlln).clone();
                    swap(self, &mut newll); // self now contains tail, newll contains the Empty
                    Some(hd)
                }
                _ => None,
            }
        }
    }

    pub struct Iter<'a, T: 'a + Clone>(*const LazyList<'a, T>);

    impl<'a, T: 'a + Clone> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
        type Item = &'a T;

        fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
            unsafe {
                if let LazyList::Cons(ref v, ref r) = *self.0 {
                    self.0 = &***r;
                    Some(v)
                } else {
                    None
                }
            }
        }
    }

    impl<'i, 'l, T: 'i + Clone> IntoIterator for &'l LazyList<'i, T> {
        type Item = &'i T;
        type IntoIter = Iter<'i, T>;

        fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
            self.iter()
        }
    }

    impl<'a, T: 'a + Clone, > FromIterator<T> for LazyList<'a, T> {
        fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item = T> + 'a>(itrbl: I) -> LazyList<'a, T> {
            let itr = itrbl.into_iter();
            #[inline(always)]
            fn next_iter<'b, R, Itr>(mut iter: Itr) -> LazyList<'b, R>
                where R: 'b + Clone,
                      Itr: 'b + Iterator<Item = R>
            {
                match iter.next() {
                    Some(val) => LazyList::cons(val, move || next_iter(iter)),
                    None => Empty,
                }
            }
            next_iter(itr)
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I've exhausted ideas on how to try and fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in the question (though not in the referenced answer, which has since been updated) relies on a soundness bug in older versions of the compiler ([#18937](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/18937)) which has since [been fixed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/37166).

It is not possible to implement `FromIterator` for `LazyList`, or indeed for any data structure, by storing the iterator inside the structure. This is because the `FromIterator` trait allows the implementor (`Self`) to outlive the iterator type (`I::IntoIter`). That the compiler ever accepted it was an oversight.

When copying code from the internet, be conscious of the age of the source. This code is also out of date in several other respects, notably:

- it uses Rust 2015-style paths
- it omits `dyn` on trait object types
- the `Invoke` workaround is no longer needed, since [`dyn FnOnce() -> T` works properly now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57943669/3650362).

Comment: Thanks, I moved the from_iter fn to the impl of LazyList, so that it was no longer subject to FromIterator's too loose requirements. This means that `(0..).collect::<LazyList<_>>()` no longer works, but that you have to `LazyList::from_iter(0..)`.

Comment: Yep, that sounds like a good compromise.